# Need help about cooling fan voltage adjustment

Tags: voltage

So, i built a custom cooling pad for my laptop. Built in battery, 3d-printed case, etc. And the fan that i used is a basic 80mm case fan rated only at 12v. I want to run faster so i thought: how about i run it at 15v? (Its running on a boost converter, step up from 4.2v) i dont really care if its going to be noisy.

So what? Is it gonna burn out faster? Break? Something else? Or is it fine?

Comment: definitely yes ...

Comment: YOu are going about this all wrong.  Define excess load software on startup, ensure dust-free, define heat sink and the maximize linear speed over heatsink not volume rate of exhaust.

Answer (score 1):

You are typically able to run fans a little higher than what they’re rated for. But just because you can doesn’t mean you should. Running 15v to a 12v will likely decrease the life of the fan. I would not recommend doing it. I recommend getting a 12v fan that is capable of producing the CFM you require instead of giving it a higher voltage than what it’s rated for.